# How can we pass multiple labels to an EKS node group via BootstrapArguments

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am aware that we can create node groups with labels via kubelet-extra-args:

```
--kubelet-extra-args --node-labels=foo=bar
```

This syntax was a bit of a surprise to me so I'm not exactly sure how to add multiple labels.

Answer (score 7):

Found it! I should have guessed but this passes things off to kubelet, which apparently takes comma separated key-value pairs joined with '='

```
--kubelet-extra-args --node-labels=alabel=foo,another=bar
```